# FileOpenPicker with appium unittest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uwp, appium

How can I handle a FileDialog in appium for a C# UWP app?

In my case, the user clicks on a button and the FileOpenPicker prompts, and the user has to select one or more files. How can I handle this FileOpenPicker in a appium UnitTest?

```
var ButtonPlusElement = AppSession.FindElementByAccessibilityId("ButtonFilePicker");
Assert.IsNotNull(ButtonPlusElement);
_ButtonFilePicker = ButtonPlusElement;
_ButtonFilePicker.Click(); // FileOpenPicker appears
//how set the selected file of the FilePicker?
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the Inspect.exe tool to figure out the name of the openfile dialog. This way I could easily access the openfile dialog controls.

The inspect.exe tool is located in the windows sdk (e.g. `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17134.0\x86\inspect.exe`)

Related issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/issues/489